# WCF Web Service authentication - recommend method?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am developing my first WCF web service which is supposed to be interacting with two additional systems. I wish to implement authentication, but I am not certain of which options I have nor which one I should choose.

It is intended only for machine-to-machine communication, so forms should be out of the question. What's the recommended method of authentication given the circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think certificate based authentication is the way to go here.
Since machine to machine communication does not involve user input I suppose.

For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx

Comment: Over TCP as well if you can.  You can also add firewall rules (as well as certs) to control which servers can talk to each other, and on what ports...it's an added level over the top of the certificate.